# Testing workflow with Cypress and React

Tags: reactjs, selenium, testing, cypress, integration-testing

I have question regarding the development and testing workflow. I am using Cypress but this topic is suitable for any end to end test.

The question is how do you selecting the elements in the browser?

1, Explicit selectors like data-cy or automation-id on each element or component.

2, Selecting the elements by visible text on the screen and then navigate to specific element by DOM hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Every test you write will include selectors for elements. To save yourself a lot of headaches, you should write selectors that are resilient to changes.

Oftentimes we see users run into problems targeting their elements because:

Your application may use dynamic classes or ID's that change
Your selectors break from development changes to CSS styles or JS behavior
Luckily, it is possible to avoid both of these problems.

Don't target elements based on CSS attributes such as: id, class, tag
Don't target elements that may change their textContent
Add data-* attributes to make it easier to target elements

```
<button
  id="main"
  class="btn btn-large"
  name="submission"
  role="button"
  data-cy="submit"
>
  Submit
</button>
```

And then for example clicking to button

```
cy.get("[data-cy=submit]")
.should("be.visible")
.click()
```

You can also search for specific text in dom.

```
cy.get("button")
.should("be.visible")
.contains("Submit")
.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for answer I got your point. But next question is, when I have reusable component like button and this button is used more times on the page. How to specify which button to select because every button will have data-cy="button". The option is passing data-cy to components as parameter but I am not sure if the component interface should be defined this way.

Comment: You could specify functionality of the button. For example if it's "send" button then you can give a name "data-cy=cy_send_btn" or if this button is for "remove" button then "data-cy=cy_remove_btn" etc. Another advice, if you have a more than one "send" button then I suggest you to use custom commands "commands.js". You can declare one submit button in this file and then using in many different files without repeating same code. See the second answer line for example.

Answer (score 0):

Custom commmands `commands.js`

```
Cypress.Commands.add("sendBtn", () => {
  cy.get("[data-cy=cy_send_btn]")
   .should("be.visible")
   .click()
})
```

And in test file

```
it("Add test description here", function() {
  .
  . 
  .
  .
  cy.sendBtn()
})
```

Custom command shown above you will be able to use multiple times in other test files for all send buttons. Your tests will be more isolated and efficient.